# Is Pandemic Legacy as good with 3 players as it is with 4?

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1

I have gathered 3 players (including myself) for Pandemic Legacy and we are eager to begin, but I'm wondering whether I should take the time to find a 4th. I've played Risk Legacy with 4 and it was a great experience. I'm somewhat concerned that the 3-player version of Pandemic Legacy won't be as deep or engaging as the 4-player version. This is just speculation, however, I have no evidence to back this up. Hence this question. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, the game was designed to be balanced at 2-4 players just like normal Pandemic. Outside of that, I'm not sure you can get an answer that isn't just someone's opinion.

Comment: The answer to this will depend on your group

Comment: This is an opinion-based question and does not fit the Q&A format for this site. Try [BGG](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/161936/pandemic-legacy) they keep track of # of player recommendations.

Comment: @freekvd - subjective questions are not banned here.  Please consult our [FAQ](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) I don't believe this question crosses any boundaries.

Comment: @PatLudwig I have rechecked the definition for "primarily opinion-based". If this question doesn't fit it, then I don't know which does.

Comment: @tsuma534 - In my opinion, the questioner is asking for folks to share their experience and expertise with the game.  Check the answers below, did they use facts, references, or specific expertise to support their opinions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We've played the game with both 3 and 4 in the same campaign.  It didn't affect the feel of the game either way.  For a variety of reasons you likely won't play the same characters in every mission anyway, so there is no reason that you can't add or drop someone part way through.

Comment: There is even a space in the occupation cards' play logs to note who played them that session.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I've played the game with 3 players (we're at the end of october right now) my feeling is a little more contrasted:

- the game works perfectly well in this configuration (and is a blast BTW)
- you might get more variation in the characters played by adding a fourth player

Our experience was that with 3 players, we almost (at least at the beginning of the campaign) always played the same subset of characters. You don't always get to play the same role as you attribute them at the end of the setup, depending on the cards in hands and the situation on the board but still. We were often arguing:

> - hey we could get use of this one this time!
> - Yeah sure, which one of the fab 3 do we remove?
> - OK let's keep'em

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the same boat...
We decided that it was better for us to start playing with 3 players than to wait for a fourth one that can be as available and motivated as the 3 of us (and possibly never play at all)...

We didn't start playing yet, but here are the way we envision it:

- The fourth spot might become available for a friend of us who would want to try the game but can't commit to the full campaign (think of it like guest-stars in the Muppet Show back in the day)
- if we feel like the game is less fun without the 4th pawn/character, as everything is open information (that's my understanding from reading the rules), we can still add it and decide collectively for its actions...